# Yocto- bitbake qt5-image - trouble creating bootable flash for rpi from result

Tags: image, yocto, sd-card, bitbake

I have been researching online for a proper way to create a bootable SD card (through USB adapter) for my raspberry pi from files created by "bitbake qt5-image" command. The build process finished successfully with no warnings or errors. Resulting files that I assume are relevant to my goal are:

in ~/rpi/build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi:

`    "modules-raspberrypi.tgz" link to

modules-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-raspberrypi-20181009142103.tgz   17.mb

```
"qt5-image-raspberrypi.tar.xz" link to

qt5-image-raspberrypi-20181009142103.rootfs.tar.xz                    92.8 mb

"zImage" link to

zImage-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-raspberrypi-20181009142103.bin    4.7mb
```

I also took some advice from this tutorial (https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html) for steps before the build.

Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Edit (I changed KERNEL_IMAGETYPE to = "Image" in build/conf/local.conf from zimage) which produced this

Content (excluding btbo files) of tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi/

```
bcm2708-rpi-0-w.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
bcm2835-bootfiles

**Image         Link to Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-raspberrypi-20181010131555.bin**

Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2708-rpi-0-w-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2708-rpi-b-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2708-rpi-b-plus-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2708-rpi-cm-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2709-rpi-2-b-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2710-rpi-3-b-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus-20181010131555.dtb
Image-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-bcm2710-rpi-cm3-20181010131555.dtb

Image-bcm2708-rpi-0-w.dtb
Image-bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
Image-bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
Image-bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb
Image-bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Image-bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
Image-bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
Image-bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb

modules-1-4.14.73+git0+e117f3e9fd-r0-raspberrypi-20181010131555.tgz

modules-raspberrypi.tgz

qt5-image-raspberrypi-20181009142103.testdata.json
qt5-image-raspberrypi-20181010131555.rootfs.manifest
qt5-image-raspberrypi-20181010131555.rootfs.tar.xz
qt5-image-raspberrypi-20181010131555.testdata.json
qt5-image-raspberrypi.manifest
qt5-image-raspberrypi.tar.xz
qt5-image-raspberrypi.testdata.json


Content of build/conf/bblayers.conf

# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf   /bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
${HOME}/poky/meta \
${HOME}/poky/meta-poky \
${HOME}/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
${HOME}/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
${HOME}/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
${HOME}/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
${HOME}/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
${HOME}/poky/meta-qt5 \
${HOME}/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
${HOME}/poky/meta-security \
${HOME}/rpi/meta-rpi \
"
```

Comment: Search for the file with `.rpi-sdimg` extention in `tmp/deploy/images/` and just dd it to your USB stick.

Comment: bitbake core-image-minimal indeed produced .rpi-sdimg and I had no problem using dd with it and it worked great. My problem is that for whatever reason I can only produce with bitbake qt5-image either zImage or .bin, I can't seem to get a WIC image or sdimg. Trying to figure out how to change file type, I'm using latest raspberrypi-meta and rpi-meta, perhaps I should not use the later one

Comment: no `ext3` image either? show us the list of files at `tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi`

Comment: show us your `bblayers.conf` as well

Comment: i'm trying to "edit" the question with new information but I have no idea why its not saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest [meta-raspberrypi](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/) layer as machine layer, then you will be getting [WIC](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/tree/conf/machine/include/rpi-base.inc#n9) image as output in `tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi`.

This image can be directly flashed into SD card as it already partitioned as,

```
# short-description: Create Raspberry Pi SD card image
# long-description: Creates a partitioned SD card image for use with
# Raspberry Pi. Boot files are located in the first vfat partition.

part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4096 --size 20
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label root --align 4096
```

So you don't need to manually partition the SD card and copy the respective files.

Comment: I am using the latest meta-raspberrypi layer, it does have WIC folder, but i'm confused on how to set bitbake to build .wic image. Is it as simple as changing the "image" variable in local.conf to "wic"?

Comment: You need to set the `WKS_FILE` variable either in machine configuration or in your desired image recipe. For example `WKS_FILE = "sdimage-raspberrypi.wks"`.